# PSGETSID script to change IE setting

Tags: file, batch-file, regedit

Has anyone made a script to change a registry file based on a users SID remotely?

I'm trying to make IE prompt that it is the default browser - we have PCs that are locked down, but Google Chrome keeps getting installed and it's being set as the default browser and it's causing issues. So an easy fix, rather than logging in as an admin is just to change a simple registry key, open IE, hit yes, and be done. The PCs I am working with are all generic usernames with similar passwords, so I'm trying to make this as easy as possible.

Here's what I have so far

```
@echo off
ECHO PC Name 
SET /P pc=
ECHO.
ECHO Generic Username Logged In 
SET /P un=
ECHO.

for /F "usebackq delims== skip=1" %%i in (`\\gtchghost\installs\PSTools\psgetsid.exe \\%pc% \%un%`) do set uSID=%%i

REG ADD "\\%pc%\HKEY_USERS\%%i\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Check_Associations" /t REG_SZ /d "yes"

pause
```

I keep getting

```
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
```

If I run this command I get the SID which is what I am trying to make a variable.

```
psgetsid \\pc \username
```

Comment: All this code: _(`\\gtchghost\installs\PSTools\psgetsid.exe \\%pc% \%un%`) do set uSID=%%i_ needs to be on the same line as the `FOR` command.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that right after posting. I was just trying to get the code to fit easier on the page. I have made that change. Thanks! Still not working though..

Comment: What are you doing with this: `\%un%`.  I don't see that in the syntax for the `PSGETSID` command usage.

Comment: When using the psgetsid command it can go `PSGETSID \\PCNAME \USERNAME` the username is the `\un` variable.

Comment: So in your version of PSGETSID you see a backslash for the syntax of the username?

Comment: I used your exact `FOR` command options, minus the slash for the username and I did not get any errors using `PSGETSID`.  But why complicate the options when all you need is: `for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"\\server\share\PSTools\psgetsid" \\server user') do set usid=%%G`

Comment: I figured it out - I was getting an error in the `REG ADD` portion of the script. Removed the `%%G` and did `%usid%` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!!